# How to prioritize mobile css over desktop css

Tags: html, css

Problem: I have a footer, that I have set up to work on a desktop view. When the footer enters into mobile view, it works like I want to, expect the text.

The text uses the css that is set on desktop view rather than the mobile view. So when I want to align all of the text to the center I can't. It uses the desktop css, meaning the first line of text will float left with margin-left: 40px; and so on.

I've tried messing around with the mobile css and have not found an answer. I feel like I'm missing something important. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and show me the solution. Would appriciate it very much!

https://jsfiddle.net/7vmb5gz8/

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="footer_info">
            <div class="footer_contact"><b>TEL:</b> 6 979 200; <b>E-Post:</b> <a class="footer_email" href="mailto:frens@frens.ee" target="_top">frens@frens.ee</a></div>
            <div class="footer_links"><a href="#" class="footer_frens_link">Frens Catering</a>; <a href="#" class="footer_shop_link">E-Pood</a></div>
            <div class="footer_rights">© Kõik õigused kaitstud. Frens 2017</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid syntax in your CSS

```
.footer_contact !important{
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Remove `!important`or change this to:

```
.footer_contact{
    float:none !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vmb5gz8/1/)

Comment: Ooooh! Makes sense. So you can't use !important on the whole class? Interesting! That works. Thank you! :)

Comment: I think you can even remove the important completely in this case!?